# How do you find the point on a graph that minimizes the distance from that point each other point?

Tags: optimization, least-squares

Say you have a set of random (x, y) points on a graph. What would the point be that minimizes the distance of this point to each other one?

I imagine you want to use some kind of least squares method, but I only know how to use that in the context of finding lines of best fit. How can I apply that knowledge here?

Comment: Well, you'd create a distance function between the point and each point on your graph, sum the functions for a generic point, and find the minimum of this function. Most likely, the function will be messy, so using a CAD or some other tool will probably be your best bet

Comment: How do you define the object function? You want to minimize $ (x_i-x_c)^2+ (y_i-y_c)^2$

Comment: What does it mean to minimize "the distance to each other one"? The total distance? The total squared distance? The maximum distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point which minimizes the distance to the furthest point in $X$ is usually called the Chebyshev center of $X$. It is the center of the smallest disk which contains $X$.

There are also other options, for instance minimizing the sum of distances to all points of $X$. This is known as the geometric median (or Fermat-Torricelli point if $|X|=3$).

You can find either with quadratic programming or second-order cone programming, so yes, it is analogous to least squares. For example the Chebyshev center can be solved with
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\mathrm{minimize} & r \\
\mathrm{s.t.} & r\geq \|y-x\|_2,\ x\in X.
\end{array}
$$

Comment: The easiest option is to minimize the sum of squared distances, which simply gives you the centroid $\frac1n\sum\vec x$.